# NodeJS - How to generate certificate and private key with node-opcua-pki

Tags: node.js, node-modules, opc-ua, node-opcua

I'm trying to establish an OPCUA connection between my NodeJS App (Client side) and an OPCUA server (not NodeJS based).
I'm using the module node-opcua and I have no problem to connect to the OPCUA server with no encryption.

However I want my connection to be secured and encrypted. I'm trying to use the module node-opcua-pki to generate certificate & private key but I don't know how to use this module and where to run this command.

Do I have to run the command to generate my certificate and private key in the command line or in my NodeJS app?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

#### using the command line

```
$ npx node-opcua-pki certificate -o mycertificate.pem
```

this will create a self-signed certificate `mycertificate.pem` in the current folder.

this will also create a pki and the associated private key in `.\certificates\PKI\own\private\private_key.pem` if not exist already.

many options are available in the command line to let you specify the location of the pki or a specific subject string for the certificate.

```
$  npx node-opcua-pki certificate --help
```

#### programmatically

```js
const certificateFolder = path.join(process.cwd(), "certificates");

const certificateFile = path.join(certificateFolder, "server_certificate.pem");

const certificateManager = new opcua.OPCUACertificateManager({
   rootFolder: certificateFolder,
});
await certificateManager.initialize();

if (!fs.existsSync(certificateFile)) {
   await certificateManager.createSelfSignedCertificate({
       subject: "/CN=MyCommonName;/L=Paris",
       startDate: new Date(),
       dns: [],
       validity: 365 * 5, // five year
       applicationUri: "Put you application URI here ",
       outputFile: certificateFile,
   });
}
const privateKeyFile = certificateManager.privateKey;
console.log("certificateFile =", certificateFile);
console.log("privateLeyFile =", privateKeyFile);
```